# Erro NoSuchElementException ao executar aplicação

Tags: java

Escrevi um código simples no online java ide (segue código abaixo):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String nome = "Filipe";    
      final double minimo = 15;    
    Scanner let = new Scanner(System.in);

    double n1;
        System.out.print("Informe a primeira nota: ");
        n1 = let.nextDouble();

    double n2;
        System.out.print("Informe a segunda nota: ");
        n2 = let.nextDouble();

    double n3;
        System.out.print("Informe a terceira nota: ");
        n3 = let.nextDouble();

    double n = (n1 + n2 + n3)/3;

    System.out.print("A media do aluno " + nome + " e " + n);    
    if (n < minimo) {
        System.out.print("O aluno foi Reprovado");
    }     
    else { 
        System.out.print("O aluno foi aprovado");
    }

  }
}
```

Mas na hora de compilar na ide online ocorreu isso:

```
Informe a primeira nota: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:23)
```

Alguém sabe me explicar o por quê?

Comment: Sou novo em java e, por isso, não sei fazer nada além de algo simples como isso --'

Comment: Onde é a linha 23?

Comment: pow cara, a linha 23 corresponde a n1 = let.nextDouble(); eu vi aqui

Comment: Provavelmente porque nada foi digitado, veja funcionando: http://ideone.com/FYmje4

Comment: isso, n tem como colocar algum dado de entrada

Comment: mas como uso esse ideone?

Comment: O erro ocorre como o @bigown explicou, nada foi digitado. Valide os valores antes de compara-los para ver se algum deles está nulo.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira indo lá e digitando um código, escolhendo a linguagem Java.

Comment: vlw ai pela ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entre aqui no [Compile e Execute Java Online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMblI5Si0yYllNWms) e peça para executar seu código. Está compilando normalmente. Ai você vai entrar com os dados referente as notas como está no código. Após digitar as 3 notas, o resultado virá avisando se foi reprovado ou não. Porém se você não inserir nenhum dado, ele acontece esse erro `NoSuchElementException` na execução. Daria para resolver seu problema usando este código abaixo. Com `Scanner`, você precisa verificar se há uma próxima linha com `hasNextLine()`, ai usando `while` você pegaria o valor até que seja digitado algo.

```
while(let.hasNextLine()){
        n1=let.nextDouble();
        break;
}
```

Mas tem um porém, o código vai depender se a entrada está formatado corretamente. Ai você teria que colocar algumas condições para as entradas.

Verja o resultado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seu código completo ficaria assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String nome = "Filipe";    
      final double minimo = 15;    
    Scanner let = new Scanner(System.in);

    double n1 = 0;
       System.out.print("Informe a primeira nota: ");
            while(let.hasNextLine()){
                n1=let.nextDouble();
                break;
            }

    double n2 = 0;
        System.out.print("Informe a segunda nota: ");
            while(let.hasNextLine()){
                n2=let.nextDouble();
                break;
        }

    double n3 = 0;
        System.out.print("Informe a terceira nota: ");
            while(let.hasNextLine()){
                n3=let.nextDouble();
                break;
        }

    double n = (n1 + n2 + n3)/3;

    System.out.print("A media do aluno " + nome + " e " + n);    
    if (n < minimo) {
        System.out.print("O aluno foi Reprovado");
    }     
    else { 
        System.out.print("O aluno foi aprovado");
    }

  }
}
```

Veja ele funcionando [aqui](http://goo.gl/MDVORK).